# How to filter out all the duplicate phone numbers in spark/sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark

**Input Table:**

| ID | Phone Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202-555-0188:202-555-0132 |
| 2 | 202-555-0104:202-555-0132 |
| 3 | 202-555-0104:202-555-0162 |
| 4 | 202-555-0181:202-555-0188:202-556-7191 |
| 5 | 518-555-0110 |

Given above table how can you filter out all the duplicate numbers in *Phone Number* Column? Numbers must be unique across the entire column, not just for that particular cell.

1. How to use RDD to achieve the same?
2. Can it be done using just SQL?

**Expected Output:**

| ID | Phone Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202-555-0188:202-555-0132 |
| 2 | 202-555-0104 |
| 3 | 202-555-0162 |
| 4 | 202-555-0181:202-556-7191 |
| 5 | 518-555-0110 |

**Explanation:**

1. 202-555-0132 - is a duplicate in row 2 from row 1, thus removed
2. 202-555-0104 - is a duplicate in row 3 from row 2, thus removed
3. 202-555-0188 - is a duplicate in row 4 from row 1, thus removed

**Assumption**: There will be atleast one unique number per row.

Comment: And there are no other columns in the table (that are of relevance)? Do you want to `DELETE` duplicates?

Comment: Filtered duplicates: `SELECT MIN(id), Phone_Number FROM myTable GROUP BY Phone_Number`

Comment: @Aconcagua this is an oversimplified version of the entire table. Also, I just want to fetch it, no need to delete any records. `SELECT MIN(id), Phone_Number FROM myTable GROUP BY Phone_Number` - I am not sure how this will work, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: `GROUP BY` groups records with the same phone number into a single record (grouping by all selected columns gets equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT`) and you can then add further columns with aggregate functions like `MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, …) that are applied on the rows *within* the groups.  Try `SELECT MIN(id), Phone_Number, COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY Phone_Number` – it adds the number of rows within the group, i. e. the number of duplicates in your case.

Comment: Side note: If you want to apply conditions to the groups themselves similar to `WHERE` you would do so by a `HAVING` clause, e. g. `SELECT Phone_Number FROM myTable GROUP BY Phone_Number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` would list only phone numbers of which duplicates exist.

Comment: @Aconcagua *Phone_Number* column itself is an array like string separated by `:`. Above query will work if each *Phone_Number* column had just one number.

Comment: Now that's problematic as you are violating 1NF already (more than one date in a single column). You are now relying on string operations which will get quite a nightmare on SQL. I would recommend a redesign of your data base such that only one single phone number is contained in a single row (separate phone number table referring person's id as foreign key). If you still want to retain your design you might be best off writing a stored procedure.

Comment: Gotcha, Can you give me a solution for this? Like, Suppose I could not change the phone number at this point. How can I write a stored procedure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array from the string, deduplicate and recreate the string (if needed):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data = Seq((1,"202-555-0188:202-555-0132"),(2,"202-555-0104:202-555-0132"))
val df=sc.parallelize(data).toDF("id","phone")
val df2=df.withColumn("ps",split($"phone",":"))
val df3=df2.withColumn("p",explode ($"ps")).drop($"ps").drop($"phone")
val df4=df3.dropDuplicates("p")
val df5=df4.groupBy($"id").agg(collect_list($"p").as("ps"))
df5.withColumn("phones",array_join($"ps",":")).drop($"ps").show(10,false)

+---+-------------------------+
|id |phones                   |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |202-555-0188:202-555-0132|
|2  |202-555-0104             |
+---+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering Spark Dataset API it's always better to use case class for schema definition.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  case class User(id: Int, phone_no: String)
  val userDS = Seq[User](User(1,"202-555-0188:202-555-0132"),User(2,"202-555-0104:202-555-0132"),User(3,"202-555-0104:202-555-0162"),User(4, "202-555-0181:202-555-0188:202-556-7191"),User(5, "518-555-0110")).toDS
  val parsedDS = userDS.map{user => (user.id, user.phone_no.split(":"))}
  val outDS = parsedDS.select($"_1".as("ID"), explode($"_2")
    .as("PhoneNo")).dropDuplicates("PhoneNo")
    .groupBy("ID").agg(concat_ws(":",collect_set($"PhoneNo")).as("Phone Number"))
    .orderBy("ID")
  outDS.show(false)
    
+---+-------------------------+
|ID |Phone Number             |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |202-555-0132:202-555-0188|
|2  |202-555-0104             |
|3  |202-555-0162             |
|4  |202-555-0181:202-556-7191|
|5  |518-555-0110             |
+---+-------------------------+
```